# PHP: how do I convert a non-truecolor image to a truecolor image?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

How to do that with GD?

Answer (score 7):

[Create a new truecolor image resource](http://docs.php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) (t) with the [same dimensions](http://docs.php.net/imagesx) as the source image (s) and then [copy](http://docs.php.net/imagecopy) (s) to (t).

e.g. (without error handling):

```
$imgSource = imagecreatefromgif('xyz.gif');
$width = imagesx($imgSource);
$height = imagesy($imgSource);
$imgTC = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($imgTC, $imgSource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
// save or send $imgTC
```

You'll have both images in memory in the gd2 format (4 bytes per pixel? 5?), so you better check your [memory_limit](http://docs.php.net/ini.core#ini.memory-limit) setting before trying this with larger images.

Answer (score 3):

Since PHP 5.5 there's a fast, easy and less memory-hungry solution: just use the [`imagepalettetotruecolor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepalettetotruecolor.php) PHP function:

```
$imgSource = imagecreatefromgif('xyz.gif');
if (!imageistruecolor($imgSource)) {
    imagepalettetotruecolor($imgSource);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/imagecreatetruecolor) to create a new image and then [imagecopy](http://php.net/imagecopy) your palette-based image onto it.